# keras-js "Error: [Model] Model configuration does not contain any layers."

Tags: javascript, python, keras

Im trying to load a simple example network created with keras in the browser using keras-js. After saving the model as .h5 file and converting it to a .bin file I get following error while loading it:

```
  *Error: [Model] Model configuration does not contain any layers.*
```

The model is simply created by:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model= Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10,input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])

inputs=[[5],[3],[4],[5]]
targets=[[5],[3],[4],[5]]

model.fit(inputs,targets,epochs=100)
model.save("example.h5")
```

Then I convert it with:

```
python encoder.py -q example.h5
```

and load it in javascript with:

```
const model = new KerasJS.Model({
filepath: '/keras/example.bin',
filesystem: true,
gpu: false
})
```

I have tried it with keras version 2.0.9, 2.1.2 and 2.1.5.
What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I knew nothing about this JS library but I tried to reproduce the problem and I really get that error you mentioned. ***HOWEVER***, a careful programmer would notice that an error previous to that mentioned error had shown up. And it was the following:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///< your_local_path_to_keras-js >/keras-js-master/example.bin' from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>   https.

You can read more about this issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local/10752078). Basically, a webapp is not allowed to access your local files due to security measures. Then, you need to serve these files, which can be easily done with the following python command:

```
python -m http.server
```

This will serve files from the current directory at localhost under port 8000:

> http://localhost:8000/

There are more alternatives to do this in this [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally).

I tried this and get rid of both errors.